# What is a good book to train drawing graphs of function?

Tags: soft-question, graphing-functions, book-recommendation

I am about undergraduate here , and I just want to ask what is the best book for drawing graph of functions as I am very weak in drawing graphs

Comment: Is sketching graphs really a deep and broad enough topic to fill a book?

Comment: Just need an graph function sketching exercise book for sketching graph , not necessary textbook

Comment: @LingMinHao: Did you try: Functions and Graphs by I. M. Gelfand , E. G. Glagoleva, E. E. Shnol (it is a Dover book - so the prices is great and you might be able to find used copies)?

Comment: Does this book cover all the graphs available until undergraduate level ? If it is , I will try it out , thanks

Comment: You can peruse sample pages and the table of contents on Amazon, but yes.

Comment: I think it's not a good manner to name any book basically if they are not in public domain or not well followed. As you know there is not any such book.

Comment: Often graphing functions is a topic in a first semester calculus course. So you might try looking at the relevant sections of calculus textbooks.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing graphs correctly is a matter of practice. And also from the elementary point of view the more you know about a function the better you can draw it's graph analytically. For starting, you may use some graphing calculators or programs, show some inquisitiveness about the graph of any function you encounter and you will gradually learn how to draw the related ones. And a vast knowledge about different graphs also come handy. I also faced that problem, so keep patience, if you follow this advice you will surely do good. So once again $-$*play with graphs*.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use a program like geogebra, wolfram alpha, Desmos or any other graphing program? to get the graphs, after you tried it first yourself?
in geogebra for example you can easily change one or two parameters in the function , to see what they do

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08K78SCWZ) "Play with graphs" by Amit M Agarwal is quite good. It starts with the basics and goes upto very complicated functions and teaches by the way of solving example problems. By the way it is quite famous in India as a high-school level companion book for competitive exams.